# Creating KPIs in Tabular Editor

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

How would I go about converting this calculation item into a KPI? I get that I should create a measure but I really need it to pick up a selected measure. Is there a way around this?

PS. I am using calculated groups and have multiple measures as rows. This newly created Calculation Item is a column.

```
CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDMEASURE() * 0.9,
    FILTER('Date Dimension', YEAR('Date Dimension'[Date]) = 2022)
)
```